# Find an inverse Laplace Transform using partial fractions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse-laplace

Problem:
Find the $\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{H(s)\}$ of the following function:
$$ H(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2+5s+6} $$
Answer:
First we use partial fractions to rewrite the fraction.
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{s^2+5s+6} &= \dfrac{A}{s+3} + \dfrac{B}{s+2} \\
1 &= A(s+2) + B(s+3) \\
\end{align*}
If we set $s = -2$ we have: $1 = A(-3+2)$. This gives us:  $A = -1$. We also know that:
$$ A + B = 0$$
Hence we have $B = 1$.
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{s^2+5s+6} &= \dfrac{1}{s+2} - \dfrac{1}{s+3} \\
f(t) &= e^{-2t} - e^{-3t} \\
\end{align*}
However, the book gets:
$$ 2 + 5e^{5t} $$
I would like to think that I am right. Am I?
I looked up the answer in the book incorrectly. The book gets:
$$ e^{-2t} - e^{-3t} $$
which matches my answer.

Comment: Your inverse transform is correct.  Perhaps you are missing some information.

Comment: @Doug What kind of information might I be missing?

Comment: What is the objective of the question?  Is it simply to do inverse transform, or is it to solve a differential equation?

Comment: Which book is it ?

Comment: @Doug The objective of the question is to find the Laplace Inverse. It is from a book on differential equations.

Comment: @user577215664 The name of the book is "Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equations" by Shepley L. Ross. It is the fourth edition. It is an old book.

Comment: I see what page ? Maybe they mix answers it happens sometimes

Comment: @user577215664 It is section 9.2 which is on page 509. It is exercise number 1.

Comment: They give the solution you find at the answers of 92B first question  at the end of the book

Comment: The answer of the textbook you posted is for 92A and your question has the correct answer in the textbook at 92B first answer

Comment: @user577215664 I looked up the answer incorrectly. Now, I realize that my answer matches the book's answer. If you post an answer that my answer is correct, I will accept it and I can close the question. Thank  you.

Comment: You're welcome Bob

Comment: Your answer is completely correct Bob no doubt about this I upvote your question for your efforts